# How to save image file directly to image gallery in android

Tags: android, picasso

Is there any good way to save image into gallary using File object?

I want to do like this

File file = new File("path to image gallery","empty.jpg");

Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg").save(file);

I believe JakeWharton meant that ??
 [picasso issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/506)